# Getting "undefined method" with Thinking Sphinx scopes when using STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Thinking Sphinx 2.0.13 with Rails 3.2.9.

Given I have and STI class that looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_index do
    has :account_id
    has :is_deleted
  end

  sphinx_scope(:by_account) do |account_id|
    {:with => {:account_id => account_id}}
  end

  sphinx_scope(:without_deleted) do
    {:with => {:is_deleted => false}}
  end
end


class Admin < User
end
```

If I attempt to use a single scope on either the User or Admin class, all is fine. I can also chain scopes together using the User model, as expected. The problem is, If I chain scopes on the Admin model, I get:

```
> Admin.by_account(1).without_deleted

NoMethodError:   Sphinx Query (2.9ms)  
  Sphinx  Found 3 results
  Admin Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('Admin') AND `users`.`id` IN (7, 8, 9)
undefined method `without_deleted' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x007fd3d95f7a08>
```

It appears to be running the query as soon as the first scope is encountered. Is there something obvious I'm missing, or does this look like an issue with TS?

Comment: User class has a db field called is_deleted? with boolean type?

Comment: @Lichtamberg - yeah, the column is there and is boolean. Either scope works fine on it's own - it's only when they are chained that it breaks.

Comment: could you show the response if you put Admin.by_account(1) into the console?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems people before you have had with `sphinx_scopes` that could be the problem here.

- People have found problems with name conflicts in their `sphinx_scopes`. Your scope `by_account` is a prime candidate for that, so try renaming it. I can imagine situations where that gets messed up in a derived class but not the base class.
- Scope problems in the past have been worked around by reordering the calls, so try `Admin.without_deleted.by_account(1)`. Not a fix, I know.
- I'd also predict that `account_id` is a primary key (i.e. at most one `User` per `Account`). If so, this could explain why `Rails` is choosing to fetch it prematurely.